# Kusto - Avgif, Min , Max and Median

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am converting the below Splunk query to Kusto
`avg(eval(if(Test="Success", Duration, null()))) as AvgDuration`

This Query will return the avg of duration if Test is success else return a null value. Could you pls advice if the below Kusto query will return the same result as I dont see the numbers matching

`| summarize AvgDuration = avgif (Duration, Test = "Success")`

Also how do I calculate the Min, Max and Median with the same condition pls. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For min and max you can do:

```
    let T = datatable(Test:string, Duration:timespan)["Success", timespan(05:03:01.78),"Success", timespan(15:00:06.28),"Success", timespan(02:03:05.98),"Fail", timespan(00:03:01.28)];            
    T 
    | summarize AvgDuration = avgif (Duration, Test == "Success"), 
                MinDuration = minif (Duration, Test == "Success"), 
                MaxDuration = maxif (Duration, Test == "Success")
```

| AvgDuration | MinDuration | MaxDuration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07:22:04.6800000 | 02:03:05.9800000 | 15:00:06.2800000 |

The percentile() aggregation function does not have the "if" version, so you will need to do a separate calculation for it. The simplest approach is to filter before the aggregation, for example:

```
    let T = datatable(Test:string, Duration:timespan)["Success", timespan(05:03:01.78),"Success", timespan(15:00:06.28),"Success", timespan(02:03:05.98),"Fail", timespan(00:03:01.28)];
    T
    | where Test == "Success"
    | summarize AvgDuration = avg(Duration), 
                MinDuration = min(Duration), 
                MaxDuration = max(Duration),
                Median = percentile(Duration, 50)
```

| AvgDuration | MinDuration | MaxDuration | Median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07:22:04.6800000 | 02:03:05.9800000 | 15:00:06.2800000 | 05:03:01.7800000 |

However, sometimes you want aggregations for the full dataset at the same time as the aggregation with the condition. If that's the case you will need to run two queries and join them. For example, say that you want to include the full count:

```
    let T = datatable(Test:string, Duration:timespan)["Success", timespan(05:03:01.78),"Success", timespan(15:00:06.28),"Success", timespan(02:03:05.98),"Fail", timespan(00:03:01.28)];
    let T1 = T 
        | summarize AvgDuration = avgif (Duration, Test == "Success"), 
                    MinDuration = minif (Duration, Test == "Success"), 
                    MaxDuration = maxif (Duration, Test == "Success"),
                    TotalCount  = count()
                | extend Dummy = 1;
    let T2 = T 
        | where Test == "Success"
        | summarize Median = percentile(Duration, 50) 
        | extend Dummy = 1;
    T1 
    | lookup T2 on Dummy
    | project-away Dummy
```

| AvgDuration | MinDuration | MaxDuration | TotalCount | Median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07:22:04.6800000 | 02:03:05.9800000 | 15:00:06.2800000 | 4 | 05:03:01.7800000 |

If there is heavy processing before the aggregation, you might want to consider using the [materialize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction) function around the calculation of `T`.

Comment: perfect.The answer is helpful. Thanks